# Storing Data matrix in two dimensional matrix (after .PV function)

Tags: excel, vba

In the code below, I am selecting two matrices from my Excel sheet, MatrixA and MatrixB

> MatrixA = [ 100 95.6 81 63]

and

> MatrixB  = [10 20 30 40]

I am trying to multiple them using the Application.PV function in Excel and storing them as a single 2-D matrix, therefore getting something like :

> MatrixC =
>   Row 1 : 10 9.5 9.1 6.5 ;
>
> Row 2: 20 19.12 18.21 12.69 ;
>
> Row 3: 30 28 27 19 ;
>
> Row 4 : 40 38 36 25

However, so far I manage to get only the first row. This is my code below

```
Public Function Persistence_times_initiation(MatrixA As Variant, MatrixB As Variant)

Dim finalArray As Variant

For i = 1 To 4
   finalArray(1,i) = Application.PV(, 1, Application.PV(, MatrixA, MatrixB(1, i)))
Next i

Persistence_times_initiation = finalArray

End Function
```

So the first instance would show

> FinalArray = 1000 956 810 630

Second instance

> FinalArrat = 2000 1912 1620 1260

Third instance

> FinalArrat = 3000 2868 2430 1890

Fourth instance

> FinalArrat = 4000 3824 3240 2520

I am trying to store this into a matrix. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Hi. U are crashing the value of finalArray every time that u iterate with i. U are only keeping Last iteration. I dont know the función PV, i dont know what it does, but to jeep all return finalArray must be a array or something like that. Good luck

Comment: I agree but when I try to write finalArray with an indice, it is consistently giving me an error

Comment: can u update the code to see how do u call the function  Persistence_times_initiation, and tell wheres the error that occurs when u try with an array

Comment: hi @LuisCurado, sorry for the late reply. I have added your request to the current question! Cheers

Comment: for what i see, the PV function doesnt accept matrix in parameters and the return is a double. also, the firt parameter is mandatory and u dont have it. i dont understant what are u trying to do..